# how to add background image in MP line chart

Tags: android, background-image, linechart

I had try two ways to set new background image in MP line chart. But can't see background image.

```
    //one way  

    binding.lineChart.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(),R.drawable.ic_img));
    
    //another way
    LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "IMS5 Abs");
    set1.setFillDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(),R.drawable.ic_img));
```